# Import large csv file using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I have a csv file, a big one, 30 000 rows. I've tried to import it using LOAD file etc.. from the terminal, as I found on google, but it didn't work. It was making the import but my table got to 30 000 rows of NULL cells.

After that I tried phpMyAdmin and there I found out that my csv was too big. I've split it in 5 using CSV Splitter. I've made the import for the first file. Everything went great. Than I tried to import the second one, but I got thos error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 35 bytes) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\import\csv.php
>   on line 370

or 1064 error sometimes.

Do you know why and how can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Increase your php's memory limit and script time, that's beacause your executing the mysql instruction through the php server.

Check your php.ini file for this vars:

```
memory_limit
max_execution_time
```

But anyway I would do it through the mysql client (terminal), check mysql doc

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/csv/file/csv_file.csv' INTO TABLE database_name.table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

[Mysql Documentation - Load Data Infile Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
[PHP Documentation - Ini core settings](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: Thank you for advice. I've done this but still the same problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: From 128 I changed to 512 and than 1024 ... And from 30 to 60.

Comment: Either I don't know how to do it, or it doesn't work... Anyway, thank you for trying.

Comment: then install mysqlworkbench and use this instruction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429827/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-mysql-workbench/11429986#11429986

Comment: For people who are not used to using MySql from the command-line, make sure you log in with a user (instead of merely starting mysql.exe). e.g.: mysql -u root -p yourpassword

Comment: In my case I did it via command line and it was super fast. Thanks @PacketTracer for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when trying to import a large file using phpMyAdmin, and am also unable to use the command in the version which I am using. To solve this I used [this CSV editor](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/) and split the file into smaller files. Worked fine when I imported each chunk separately.