# import text file into mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import, mysql-workbench

I was wondering how to import text file into MySQL workbench?

I have a text file delimited by `|` and the first row are the tables,

```
FEATURE_ID|FEATURE_NAME|FEATURE_CLASS
```

then it follows by data information after that

```
1388627|Etena|Populated Place
```

What is the best way to import this .txt file into MySQL workbench?

Thanks1

Comment: Do you want to import data into mysql db? Or something else?

Comment: @peterm I would like to import data into MySQL

Comment: but how exactly do I do so? If my file shows the tables in the first row and then follow data after that?

Comment: Is it tables, or column names for a table?

Comment: @peterm Those are column names for a table

Comment: Just create that table (see updated answer) version. If columns in file and in the table match than it will load successfully with `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement that I gave.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import a csv file into MySQL workbench?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429827/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-mysql-workbench)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you intend to achieve, but if you want to import delimited text file into db then you can use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) like this:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file.txt' 
INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**UPDATE:**

First of cause you need to create the table (if it's not done yet) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `FEATURE_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `FEATURE_NAME` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FEATURE_CLASS` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FEATURE_ID`)
)
```

You might need to adjust data types, lengths, and constraints on that table. For example you might not need a PK on that table.

Comment: Maybe I just follow this and just write in the column names myself?