# MySQL import txt data

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, load-data-infile

I am having some problems with mysql importing text into a database.
My .txt file looks like this:

### a.txt

```
Pattern: 1

Address: 18PhQkzkzP6QUmWuiddhJ2YrGKZKRmV3j

Privkey: 5JRpLiEcq57ijgfVGmmE19V1F29zPkwWjTQinJJJpfYtqA3ZcbY

Pattern: 1

Address: 18zvgu7k8WxAnwgghdudhdzYRCo7aEVPBUU

Privkey: 5JmAp8QgujxDhwJHwgkW9FkiuWEkSDwZL73Xu8ihAY2fy3Kjmn3  

etc....
```

I want to import this txt. file into a database called bitcoin with the table a from a.txt.
All lines from the `"Pattern: 1"` should disappear and the table "a" should only have two columns:" address and privkey" which address as the prim. key.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/weber/Desktop/a.txt" INTO TABLE a

-> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'

-> LINES STARTING BY 'Address' 

-> IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Seems not working very well, anyone with some mysql knowledge could give me a hint, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313708/import-text-file-into-mysql-workbench). Your text file is also not in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that the file can use more than one line in the text file for a row. You need to use one line per row.

Try:

```
Pattern:Address:Privkey
1:18PhQkzkzP6QUmWuiddhJ2YrGKZKRmV3j:5JRpLiEcq57ijgfVGmmE19V1F29zPkwWjTQinJJJpfYtqA3ZcbY
1:18zvgu7k8WxAnwgghdudhdzYRCo7aEVPBUU:5JmAp8QgujxDhwJHwgkW9FkiuWEkSDwZL73Xu8ihAY2fy3Kjmn3
```

And do not use the "LINES STARTING BY 'Address'" in the command. Read up at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html or something similar for info on using that properly.