# Read the field names and detect datatype of a text file for table creation

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to upload a large text file into MySQL in the terminal.

I found this SO post with an answer explaining it: [import text file into mysql workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313708/import-text-file-into-mysql-workbench)

Seems one must first create a table in MySQL that has the same field titles as the .txt file column titles and each field data type must be determined first.

The answer in the linked SO example gave:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `FEATURE_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `FEATURE_NAME` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FEATURE_CLASS` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FEATURE_ID`)
)
```

My question is, rather than having to create the table to load into in sql first, can't I just tell mySQL to "Read the text file and create a field out of each column witht he first row being the head. Look at each column of data and magically figure out what data type it is e.g. FEATURE_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL. Rather time consuming if there are lots of fields.

Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that MySQL will do this directly for you, but you're right that it will be painful to create the table structure by hand if you have a lot of columns.

You probably want to build the data definition language (DDL) statement programmatically, either in some language external to the database, or in SQL. You could write some logic to determine the type of your fields automatically and set the column types accordingly, or you *might* be willing to put up with `VARCHAR(WIDTH)` columns everywhere.

Also, I'm assuming that when you say "text file", it's a file in a CSV-like format that has fields delimited in some way (with a specific separator character). This will also be a pre-requisite to being able to load the table easily.

Incidentally, if this is just part of a larger job, or something that you're going to be doing often, you might want to look around for "ETL tools". They may offer you a less painful way of dealing with this.

**Edit**

Note that either of these approaches is inherently risky: you're either hoping that your algorithm looks at enough data to infer the correct type of the column, or you're dispensing with any data typing at all (which is an important part of validation).

I've heard some war stories about MS Access automatically and incorrectly inferring data types from data based on the head of a file, but the exceptions which correctly identified the type were buried deeper in the file.

Unless this is a throwaway case, you might want to go through the pain of correctly typing the columns to save yourself more pain later.

Thanks to Dan Bracuk for drawing attention to this caveat.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Correct, it's a | deliminated .txt file. I figured I'd have to write some script to do this and it's probably easy to the average experienced programmer. I'm sure I could do it but it'd take me a fair amount of time to figure it out. I was just checking if there was some magic SQL command! Cheers though

Comment: No worries. I just edited my answer to mention ETL tools. Might be worth a web search depending on the scale of your job.

Comment: There is no magic command.  Let's say your first column had values of 1,2, 3, and fred.  What are you going to do?  Besides, if you are willing to accept just any old text file and base your database design on it, you are being unwise.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for pointing this out. I hope it's OK that I've edited my answer to include this important warning.