# Import csv file to populate data in a table in Netbeans

Tags: java, database, csv, netbeans, import

I am very new to Java and Netbeans.I am trying to populate my table created in my database with data but the csv file contains about 1000 odd entries.Is there a way in which i can just import the data to their columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To start with, use OpenCSV to parse your data. After that, it depends on your database and what software package you intend to use to write into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using JavaDB that comes bundled with Netbeans (to be more accurate: it's included with the JDK).

You can use the import table command: `SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE`.
Check: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefimportproc.html.

As an example:

- go here: http://www.andrewpatton.com/countrylist.html and download `Country List downloadable as CSV`.
- create a table which you can name `COUNTRY` and as columns the names in the first line of the downloaded csv file. First column name: SortOrder should be the primary key. Add the rest columns as VarChar columns with size 100. Do the same for the rest but **be careful not to mess with the order of the columns** as you cannot change it later.  What I mean is that the order of the columns that you create in your table, should follow the order of the columns in the csv file. For example "Sort Order" should be created first, then create,"Common Name", then "Formal Name" ....

[image: add columns]

- then remove the first line from the csv file (the column names)
- execute the following command `CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE (null,'COUNTRY','c:\countrylist.csv',',','"',null,0);`
- select the table that you created , right click it and click `View data`.

Thats it !

If you are using MySQL check:

- [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)
- [How to import a csv file into MySQL workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429827/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-mysql-workbench)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but when i try to execute the command i am getting an error "PROCEDURE syscs_util.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE does not exist"

Comment: Which version of Netbeans and JDK are you using?

Comment: How do you execute the command? I do it like: right click on the COUNTRY table of JavaDB and click "Execute Command..."

Comment: I am using netbeans 8 and JDk 1.8.0 and i executed the command in the same manner as you did.

Comment: But i have connected Mysql to netbeans