# How to import excel data to mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, vba, excel

I have an excel sheet that contains many fields. I have a database that contains many tables which are linked to 1 another. The fields that excel sheet contains get inserted to multiple tables which are linked to 1 another.

Eg sample.xls or .xlsx

```
id | Name  | Number    | Designation
1  | manan | 987654321 | software eng.
```

Database : personal table

```
id | Name  | Number    | Desig_Id
1  | manan | 987654321 | 1
```

Database : Designation table

```
Desig_id | Designation Name
1        | software eng.
```

This is just a sample I have many tables linked at the same time. How shall i import like  this type of data?

Comment: Since my answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted so the thread can be considered closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break all your records into multiple tables, as they are in you database.
You will create one excel file per table and import it using [mysql-excel mechanism](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-append.html). You can also export the excel files as `.csv` and import it directly either by using [MySQL Workbench or by command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429827/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-mysql-workbench)

Another way, if you don't want to normalize the excel file, is to parse the file and import it programmatically. You can use [apache-poi](https://poi.apache.org/) to read the excel file, or you can export the excel file as csv file and parse it as a text file.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Workbook wb = null;
        InputStream inp = null;
        try {
            // InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");
            inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    System.out.println(getCellValue(cell));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try { if(wb != null) wb.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
            try { if(inp != null) inp.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }

    private static Object getCellValue(Cell cell) {
        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING :
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC : 
            return cell.getNumericCellValue();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN : 
            return cell.getBooleanCellValue();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR : 
            return cell.getErrorCellValue();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA : 
            return cell.getCellFormula();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK :
            return null;
        default : 
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The excel sample (xlsx)

```
id  Name    Number  Designation
1   manan_1 9876543211  software eng._1
2   manan_2 9876543212  software eng._2
3   manan_3 9876543213  software eng._3
```

Dependencies (Maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Apache-poi should be useful because there are are tons of records and I can't you know individually create different excel sheet for that. How to grab particular column using Apache POI?

Answer (score 1):

The coding itself is a bit complicated but if you want a simple answer; you can interact with a database from Java using [JDBC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) and you can interact with an Excel file from Java using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) (their [how-to](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) page is very useful).

Comment: How to grab particular column using Apache POI?

Comment: @MananPatel you can loop through the rows and get the cell in that column for each row: `for(int i=0; i<sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){Cell c = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(columnNumber);//Whatever you want to do with the cell}`. `Cell` has a bunch of methods you can use including a bunch of get methods for different data types to get the value in the Cell. (Ex: `.getStringCellValue()` which returns the value of a cell as a `String`.

Comment: @MananPatel if you use that for loop make sure you use `i <= sheet.getLastRowNum()`. I only wrote `<`