# mySQL datetime import issue from csv

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, datetime-format

I am trying to import a csv into mySQL workbench and I am running into a persistent issue with datetime fields.

The datetime that I set on the csv is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS which seems to be the mySQL standard.
At the moment of import with the Wizard from workbench- if I set the fields to datetime the import finished with 0 rows imported. [my settings on import, pretty much tried all combinations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTqOa.png)

SO I am now importing everything as text and then trying to convert altering the format, setting the fields to DATETIME (doesn't allow DATETIME() ) [setting to datetime after import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtNZB.png)

When I now run the alter script it fails saying that the first timestamp field has incorrect datetime value.. I am not even sure this is the actual issue now. [altering script fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD8kB.png)

Any idea?

Find screenshots of the various steps on the links provided.
Thank you for the support.

I already saw the post here -> [In MySQL Workbench, using "Table Data Import Wizard" to import CSV creates empty table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898767/in-mysql-workbench-using-table-data-import-wizard-to-import-csv-creates-empty)

Comment: It would be much simpler to help you if you could post just a few lines of said CSV file, and your mySQL database schema.

Comment: _"When I now run the alter script it fails saying that the first timestamp field has incorrect datetime value.."_ .. what is the actual incorrect data? not in your csv file but the one already imported in your table as text.