# Importing CSV into MySQL Workbench with text fields that have newlines in data

Tags: php, mysql, csv, upload, mysql-workbench

Tried loading csv from a spreadsheet into MySQL Workbench using a solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429827/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-mysql-workbench)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/csv/file/model.csv' INTO TABLE test.dummy FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The data loaded but some cells in the spreadsheet already contain new line characters. In these cases the LOAD created a new record.

```
Mathematics Kindergarten,Counting,"Say the number sequence 0 to 1000 forward and backward by:
- 5s, 10s or 100s, using any starting point 
- 3s, using starting points that are multiples of 3
- 4s, using starting points that are multiples of 4
- 25s, using starting points that are multiples of 25."
```

With a Table Like in this format:

```
 Course   |   Topic    | Description
```

The data loaded like so:

```
Mathematics Kindergarten   |    Counting    | "Say the number sequence 0 to 1000 forward and backward by:
- 5s, 10s or 100s, using any starting point              |                | 
- 3s, using starting points that are multiples of 3      |                | 
- 4s, using starting points that are multiples of 4      |                | 
- 25s, using starting points that are multiples of 25."  |                |
```

How can I have the system recognize to load the data so that the whole cell contains the full description and it's not broke over X records.

Answer (score 0):

The steps had me return to the document that I exported the CSV. I had to sanitize the data.

Find and Replace `Carriage Returns` and `Newline` Character present in cells with `\n`.
Also found some other cells that had comma `,` into html number `&#44;`

This corrected the issues with the data import tool of MySQL Workbench.